# How to read a big file with ReadFile function

Tags: c++, api, readfile

I have a big file (500mb), I know how to read this file with ReadFile function

but I want to read 100mb by 100mb

I mean I want to read the file in the while loop, in the first loop I read the first 100mb of file, second time read the second 100mb(from 101 to 200), ...

**for example** I have a file that contains `abdcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` now I want to read `abcd` at first, then read `efgh`, then `ijkl` and so on...

Thanks for help

Comment: 500 milligrams is not *that* big...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Are you kidding? 500 milligrams of bytes would be like yottabytes!

Comment: @AndyG, you're thinking new technologies. Old-school platter-based hard drives have a surprisingly low count of bytes for 500 mg :)

Comment: sorry It was a punctuation mistake, my language is not English

Comment: @joe: No worries. Was just a little serendipitous fun. As for your question, it's not very well described. It sounds like you're using Windows' [ReadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx), but this isn't mentioned. You also need to provide your attempt at it. A more specific question about exactly what isn't working will help get your question answered.

Comment: @AndyG  yes, I'm using Windows' ReadFile, for example I have a file that contains `abdcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` now I want to read `abcd` at first, then read `efgh`, then `ijkl` and so on...

Comment: @joe: You can edit your question with additional details. Also, is there a reason you need to use ReadFile over any standardized file reading utilities in C++?

Comment: it's a lesson and teacher said we should use just API functions

Comment: Is there a way to read the file one time, and then copy it 100mb by 100mb in a buffer? (the image has null)... :(

Answer (score -2):

As far as I understood you want to read the file chunk by chunk?

in short the logic is:

```
get the size of the file or read till ReadFile return error
while (a chunk larger than zero could be read)
{
  write chunk to output
}
```

IN other words: The easiest way is first to get the file size :

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("c:\\myFile", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL); 
DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
```

and now define your loop. Read chunks up to 1024 bytes. Of course you can use larger buffer.

```
BYTE buffer[1024];
while(read is less than remain ) {
  ReadFile(hFile, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &dwRead, NULL)
// append what you just read to some global buffer
}
```

Search in google for "read file in chunks" and you will find large amount of examples.

Comment: thanks, but with this code I can read just 1024 first bytes  of file, what about the second 1024 bytes???

Comment: This is a pseudo code. It shows you just the raw idea of how to do it. Also it will read the file till the end. E.g. will call ReadFile multiple times.

Comment: You don't need to get the file size beforehand, and that technique will fail if the file grows. `ReadFile()` provides an end if file status, which is all you need.